# free with dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free

I have this C code:

```
int main()
{
    int *p=(int *)malloc(100);   //100 bytes

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        p++;
    }

    free(p);

    return 0;
}
```

Now my question is will free(p) free all the 100 bytes or only 90 bytes. How does free() know how many bytes to free..?

Comment: None of your code makes any sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's illegal.

The argument of `free` must be a pointer that is returned by `malloc` or its cousins, or a null pointer. In your example, `p` has changed its value by `p++`.

Comment: It's also worth noting that a typical implementation of `malloc` and `free` stores the size of the allocation (possibly along with other meta-information) immediately prior to the visible part of the pointer. But there are other implementations, e.g. using external trees.